# Incompatible operand types ('const std::nullopt_t' and 'long')

Tags: c++

Всем привет

Есть следующий код:

```
optional<ssize_t> Socket::ReadWithoutHangCheck(void *buffer, size_t size) {
    auto result = read(_socketFileDescriptor, buffer, size);
    return result == -1 ? nullopt : result;
}
```

Почему если не привести `nullopt` явно к `optional<ssize_t>`, то есть, к примеру, сделать так:

```
return result == -1 ? static_cast<optional<ssize_t>>(nullopt) : result;
```

То выскакивает ошибка `Incompatible operand types ('const std::nullopt_t' and 'long')`?

Я понимаю, что означает эта ошибка, но не понимаю, почему там в принципе происходит несоответствие типов. Разве тернарный оператор не будет здесь обозначать что-то типа:

```
if (result == -1) 
    return nullopt 
else 
    return result;
```

К слову, так ошибки нет в несоответствии типов.

Comment: Если вы напишите так `auto t = result == -1 ? 1 : 1LL;`, то какой тип будет у переменной `t`? `int` или `long long`? Тернарный оператор пытается вывести некоторый общий тип на основании типов своих операндов. Иногда это возможно. В приведённом примере тип `t` — это `long long`. А иногда нет. В вашем случае не получается вывести общий тип для `const std::nullopt_t`и `long`. И тот факт, что оба неявно приводятся к `optional<ssize_t>`, никак не помогает оператору  `?:` вывести общий тип.

Comment: @wololo, ну вот я так и подумал, спасибо, что теперь убедили меня в этом на 100%)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Блок](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) `if-else` и [оператор](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other) `?:` - разные вещи.

У тренарного оператора результаты должны приводится к общему типу. (см. [std::common_type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type))

то есть код

```cpp
return cause ? A : B;
```

преобразуется к виду

```cpp
using common_type = std::common_type_t<decltype(A), decltype(B)>
return cause ? common_type{A} : common_type{B};
```

В данном случае такого общего типа не найдено.

скорее всего у [optional](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/optional) не найден подходящий конструктор неявного преобразования